# How to use quotes in PHP code in PhpStorm on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, keyboard, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using a Logitech K120 keyboard (105 keys) on Ubuntu 20.04 and in all other applications I can use the quotes (double and single), but in PhpStorm I can't. It happens to me with quotes and other characters like '`~`'.

What should I do? I have already used `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution in this issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

You must change the IBUS setting on the keyboard. I did it in the same graphical mode without using any commands (I'm not very good at that yet).

PS: You must restart the PC or at least log out.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked for me. I also added the English (US) layout to the keyboard settings and it worked perfectly